# Grails plugin cannot depends on other grails plugin?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am using grails 2.2.1, in windows.

I want to develop a plugin which depends on spring-security-core plugin, so I add dependency into BuildConfig.groovy of my plugin:

```
plugins {
    compile ':spring-security-core:1.2.7.3'
}
```

Then in my grail application project, I specify the dependency in BuildConfig.groovy in:

```
grails.plugin.location."xxxxx" = "../grails-plugins/xxxx"
```

After that, when I try to refresh dependency of my grail application project, it always prompt

```
unable to resolve class org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
```

this class is a class depends on by spring-security-core plugin and my plugin use this class too.

Is it a grails bug? or I miss something? Please help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested here. In Grails 2.2.1 you need to set `legacyResolve` to `true` since

> Grails 2.2 no longer uses the BuildConfig of the plugin for dependency
>   resolution and only uses data provided by POMs

When you set this and refresh dependencies the install messages of Spring Security Core will appear.

Comment: Thanks, I should set legacyResolve to my plugin project or my grail app project? And one question, the document also says it's not recommended, what does it mean when it say POMs, I need to define POMs for plugin? I didn't see relevant document

Comment: You need to set this in your app, that will declare the inline plugin. When you're done testing, you can install your plugin in the maven local and back it to false. POM references to the [maven POM](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html), Grails will accept what is valid in this structure scopes (compile, test etc).

Comment: Thanks, it works only when I set both the app project and plugin project to true, don't know the reason.